# A lm() dynamic function - R

Tags: r, lm

Let's assume I have this dataframe:

```
N <- 50
df  <- data.frame(
  LA1 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  LA2 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  LA3 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  LA4 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  LA5 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  LA6 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  LA7 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  LA8 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  LAY = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),

  UF1 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  UF2 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  UF3 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  UF4 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  UF5 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  UF6 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  UFY = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),

  EK1 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  EK2 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  EK3 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  EK4 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  EK5 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  EK6 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  EK7 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  EK8 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  EK9 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  EK10 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  EK11 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  EK12 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  EKY = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),

  Z1 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), 
  Z2 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  Z3 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE)
  )
```

Where I want to compute this models:

```
m1=lm(formula = LAY ~ LA1+LA2+LA3+LA4+LA5+LA6+LA7+LA8, data = df)
m11=step(m1,direction="both")

m2=lm(formula = UFY ~  UF1+UF2+UF3+UF4+UF5+UF6,data = df)
m22=step(m2,direction="both")

m3=lm(formula = EKY ~  EK1+EK2+EK3+EK4+EK5+EK6+EK7+EK8+EK9+EK10+EK11+EK12, data = df)
m33=step(m3,direction="both")

m8=lm(formula = Z1 ~ LAY+UFY+EKY, data = df)
m88=step(m8,direction="both")

m9=lm(formula = Z2 ~ LAY+UFY+EKY, data = df)
m99=step(m9,direction="both")

m10=lm(formula = Z3 ~ LAY+UFY+EKY, data = df)
m100=step(m10,direction="both")
```

As you can see, if the dimensionality of the database increases (increasing the number of `LA`, `UF`, or `EK` independent variables) I will have to modify manually the input for the models). So, I'm looking for a way to:

- Given a certain quantity of independent variables (could be 5, 10, 30 or more) for a given category (`LA`, `UF`, and `EK`), the input for the model changes automatically.

Even I have found different syntax to compute the models (like `X*Z = [(X+Z)^3]`), I can't find a way to make this computation more dynamic.

Considerations:

- The number of independent variables (`LA`, `UF`, `EK`) can change.
- The number of dependent variables (`LAY`, `UFY`, `EKY`) never changes.
- From the output of this models is extracted the coefficient vector (just in case this one).

Comment: You can build formulae with the `reformulate()` function. You can use string pattern matching on the names of your data.frame to gather the vectors that contain the response and covariates.